# dotConnect: CROSS APPLY is not supported by Oracle Database 11g

Tags: c#, oracle11g, ef-code-first, dotconnect, entity-framework-6.1

I'm trying to execute this code block using devart **dotConnect 8.4 + EF6.1**:

```
var menus = (from m in dbSet
             from p in m.RegraAcesso.Perfis
             from u in p.Usuarios
             where u.Id == userId && m.Pai.RegraAcesso.Token.Equals(module)
             select m)
            .Include(p => p.Pai)
            .ToList();
```

But it throws this error:

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: **System.NotSupportedException:** CROSS APPLY is not supported by Oracle Database 11g and lower. Oracle 12c or higher is required to run this LINQ statement correctly. If you need to run this statement with Oracle Database 11g or lower, rewrite it so that it can be converted to SQL, supported by the version of Oracle you use.

I'm using:
**dotConnect for Oracle 8.4.171.0 + EF6.1 (Code-First) + Oracle 11g**

It was working with **dotConnect for Oracle 7.5.164.0 + EF4 (Code-First) + Oracle 11g**

Comment: Anyone facing the OUTER APPLY error with dotConnect, read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/q/74415752/129580

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OUTER APPLY/CROSS APPLY constructions are supported by Oracle server starting from the 12c version. Our implementation in dotConnect for Oracle avoids generation of OUTER APPLY/CROSS APPLY if it is possible, but some LINQ queries cannot be translated without employing OUTER APPLY/CROSS APPLY. In this case you should rewrite your LINQ statement.

Also, with the development of the Entity Framework engine, the OUTER APPLY/CROSS APPLY constructions may start to be generated in cases, in which earlier were not generated. Thus, we also recommend you to create a small test project and contact the CodePlex support: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/

Comment: I rewrote my query and it is workin now. But I can not do it in a single query without the the multiple *from* in my initial LINQ statement, because of relationships. Thank you for the support.

Comment: @devart, you, the creator of the dotConnect product, should produce some examples of ways to work around these shortcomings of your product and post them here!