# LINQ avoid OUTER APPLY Oracle 11g

Tags: c#, oracle, linq, devart, dotconnect

When running the LINQ Query below against Oracle 11g instance, it will throw an OUTER APPLY not supported error.

```cs
var shipmentDetails = (
    from r in _db.XXF_SHIPMENT_DETAILs 
    where r.SHIP_TO == tradingPartnerId && r.PICKUP_DATE >= pickUpDate 
    select r)
    .GroupBy(x => x.HEADERID)
    .Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault());
```

> "OUTER APPLY is not supported by Oracle Database 11g and lower. Oracle
> 12c or higher is required to run this LINQ statement correctly. If you
> need to run this statement with Oracle Database 11g or lower, rewrite
> it so that it can be converted to SQL, supported by the version of
> Oracle you use."

Comment: Which ORM do you use? EF Core 6 should translate this query to do not use OUTER APPLY.

Comment: using LinqConnect from devArt  https://www.devart.com/linqconnect/

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use simple statements to achieve the results you are after. Referencing the query above, we...

First, get all the shipments. Use the `.ToList()` to force query execution

```
var shipmentDetails = (from r in _db.XXF_SHIPMENT_DETAILs where r.SHIP_TO == tradingPartnerId && r.PICKUP_DATE >= pickUpDate select r).ToList();
```

Now `.GroupBy()` and `.Select()` to filter - but this will be done in memory and not at the server level therefore avoiding the unsupported OUTER APPLY

```
var uniqueShipmentsWithDistinctHeaderIds = shipmentDetails.GroupBy(x => x.HEADERID).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query which will get latest record from the group:

```cs
var filtered = db.XXF_SHIPMENT_DETAILs 
    .Where(r => r.SHIP_TO == tradingPartnerId && r.PICKUP_DATE >= pickUpDate);

var grouped = fltered
    .GroupBy(r => r.HEADERID)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        HEADERID = g.Key,
        LastId = g.Max(x => x.Id)
    });

var shipmentDetails = 
    from s in filtered
    join g in grouped on s.LastId equals g.Id
    select s;
```

Still not the best as raw SQL and window functions, but should give much better performance than processing data on the client side.